# py.telebot Проблема в обработке цикла if. Как разделить цикл на 2 части?

Tags: python, telebot, if

Сразу оговорюсь, я самоучка и совсем недавно пытаюсь в Питон и вообще во все это.Существует недокод для бота с py.telebot. Я 3 дня пытаюсь понять, как решить эту проблему : Бот должен выдавать выбор из нескольких вариантов для решения задачек. В данном виде он по нажатии кнопок действительно выдает либо 1 Вариант, либо 2 Вариант. Проблемы начинаются на обработке ответов. Я понимаю, что в недокоде написано, что если ответ совпал, то все ОК, я не могу понять саму суть, как разделить Вариант 1 и Вариант 2 на два разных блока. Чтобы при выдаче ботом 1 Варианта заданий он проверял ответ только от 1 Варианта. Без телеграма, просто в idle реализовывал через while True. Не понимаю,как реализовать аналог в боте.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types # для указание типов
import time

bot = telebot.TeleBot('5549853144:')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Старт")
    markup.add(btn1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Здравствуй.Нажимай на кнопку по готовности".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):  
  
   if (message.text == "Старт"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Вариант1")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Вариант2")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Выбирай один из вариантов".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

   if(message.text == "Вариант1"):
       photo = open('Prims\Prim2\z1.png','rb') #задание1
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo) 
       photo = open('Prims\Prim1\z1.png','rb') #задание2
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo) 
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Впиши все ответы через точку с запятой - ;")
         
   if(message.text == "3;6"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Пройдено")
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Верно".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)
 
   if(message.text == "Вариант2"):
       photo = open('Prims\Prim1\z1.png','rb') #Задание1
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo) 
       photo = open('Prims\Prim2\z1.png','rb') #Задание2
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo) 
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Впиши все ответы через точку с запятой - ;")

   if(message.text == "6;3"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Nice")
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Верно".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

    

    
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Пробовал через регистрацию новых шагов, тоже не получилось.
Приму любую критику.

Answer (score 0):

В данной реализации можно использовать переменную, которая будет показывать какой вариант был выбран, например

```
if message.text == "Вариант1":
    option = 1
    твой код
```

Насколько я понял 3;6 - это ответы после выбора варианта, тогда в проверку можно добавить option:

```
if message.text == "3;6" and option == 1:
    твой код
```

В питоне не нужно ставить скобки в таких простых условиях

Comment: Если ввести ответ от Варианта 2 , когда вызвал Вариант1, то ругается, что функция используется до обозначения.

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\pyton\Бот.py", line 47, in func
    if message.text == "6;3" and option == 2 :
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'option' referenced before assignment

Comment: Можно в начале приложения обозначить option = None

Comment: Увы,но не помогло. Если вставлять ' option = None ' после 'def func(message): ' , то он останавливает бота и ответа вообще никакого нет. Если до, то выдает ту же ошибку., что запрошено до обозначения.